# aspnet-codegenerator identity list option result in scaffolding failed error

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-identity, scaffolding

Walking through this tutorial [Scaffold Identity in ASP.NET Core projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=netcore-cli).

I did everything as written, so here are the steps to reproduce:

1. Create a .net core project (named "DotNetCorePlayGround" with vs 2019).
2. From the package manager console run this commands:

   `dotnet tool install -g dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator`
3. And:

   `dotnet add dotnetcoreplayground package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design
   dotnet add dotnetcoreplayground package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design
   dotnet add dotnetcoreplayground package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore
   dotnet add dotnetcoreplayground package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI
   dotnet add dotnetcoreplayground package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
   dotnet add dotnetcoreplayground package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools`

And everything worked as expected and the resulted is:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI" Version="3.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="3.1.3">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="3.1.3">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets" Version="1.10.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="3.1.2" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

The problem is with this line (only trying to list the Identity scaffolder options):

```
dotnet aspnet-codegenerator identity -h
```

The result is:

```
dotnet : Scaffolding failed.
At line:1 char:1
+ dotnet aspnet-codegenerator identity -h p C:\Users\[user]\sou ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Scaffolding failed.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

Could not find project file in C:\Users\[user]\source\repos\DotnetCoreplayGround
```

Any idea why it can not find the project file?

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: Hey @AnatolyNikolaev I'm afraid not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to run:

`dotnet aspnet-codegenerator -help` and got **Scaffolding failed error**.
Problem was that my `.config` folder was deleted ( I do not why)...

How I solved the problem:

I create a new `.config` folder and a new `dotnet-tools.json` file in there.

Content of the file:

```
{
  "version": 1,
  "isRoot": true,
  "tools": {
    "dotnet-ef": {
      "version": "3.1.3",
      "commands": [
        "dotnet-ef"
      ]
    },
    "dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator": {
      "version": "3.1.1",
      "commands": [
        "dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Then go to terminal and run dotnet tool restore.

And that's it!